# Volume of the surface bounded by $x=\sin(y+\frac{\pi}{2})+2, -2\le{y}\le2, x\ge0$ rotated about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm trying to solve this question on an assignment and I'm getting confused, especially since it's rotating about the x-axis and the question says disk method.
The formula for the disk method is $V = \int{{\pi}f(x)^{2}dx}$
and the function is $f(y)$. How do I solve this?

Comment: Check if you can have any substitutions or change the subject. For example, which axis is it revolved around in the disk method? Which of the axes is the input and which is the output?

Comment: $-2 \le y \le y$ is this valid?

Comment: Well, the easy part is writing the equation for $y$ as a function of $x$. The harder part is the resulting integral for the disk method. Although messy, the integral can be found by standard methods. But you should include your own honest efforts to solve this as part of the question rather than just asking someone to solve it for you.

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking for the *volume* of the *solid* or the *area* of the *surface*. The **volume** of the **surface** is zero.